# normalize column data with average value of that column with awk

Tags: awk, sum, average, normalize

I have 3 columns in a data file look like below and continues up to 250 rows:

```
0.9967   0.7765   0.5798
0.9955   0.7742   0.5767
0.9942   0.7769   0.5734
```

I want to normalise each column based on the average value of that column.
I am using the code below (e.g. for column 1) but it does not print my desired output.

The results should be very close to 1

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sum+= $1; next}{avg=(NR/sum)}FNR>1{print($1/avg)}' f.dat f.dat
```

expected output for first column.

1.003

1.001

0.9988

Comment: What is your normalization logic?

Comment: just calculate the average for each column and then divide each row value by the average

Comment: Do you want to print the normalization value as one row or update all the rows with the new value? (Can you show the expected output)

Comment: @bobcat while this is a big improvement from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62552034/1745001), you're still missing some of the fundamentals of how to ask a question in this forum - we need a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to be able to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your input, output, and code properly. See how @Inian formatted the input and code for you initially for an example and apply that to your expected output. Don't show the expected output for just 1 column unless you want a tool that only outputs that 1 column, simply show the complete expected output for your posted sample input.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need separate placeholders for storing the sum and the count of columns. Recommend using an array for storing it for each column.

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {
        for (col=1; col<=NF; col++) {
            avg[col] += $col
            len[col] += 1
        }
        next
    }
    {
        for (col=1; col<=NF; col++) {
            colAvg = avg[col]/len[col]
            printf "%.3f%s", $col/colAvg, (col<NF ? FS : ORS)
        }
    }

' file file
```

Or if you want to update the entire table with the new normalized values, drop the `FNR==1` from the above snippet. If you want to increase the precision of the averaged value, change `%.2f` to how many digits you want as preferable

Comment: it prints one value for all columns and rows!!

Comment: @bobcat: As I said in the answer, if you want to update the entire table drop the `FNR==1` (Moreover, you never showed an expected output)

Comment: @bobcat: What do you mean? What is your expected output? you still haven't answered that

Comment: it is not complicated. single value in each array divided by the average value for each column. that simple.

Comment: @bobcat If you feel its that simple, why don't you edit the question to show, the expected output for the three row input that you added?

Comment: @bobcat: See edits, it should get you the expected output (likely)